# k8s - Keep pod up even if sidecar crashed

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with a sidecar. The sidecar does file synchronisation and is optional. However it seems that if the sidecar crashes, the whole pod becomes unavailable. I want the pod to continue serving requests even if its sidecar crashed. Is this doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set pod's `restartPolicy` to `Never`. It will prevent the `kubelet` from restarting your pod even if one of your containers failed.

> If a Pod is running and has two Containers. Container 1 exits with failure. If the `restartPolicy` it set to `Never`, the kubelet will not restart Container and the Pod's phase stays Running.

- [Reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#example-states)

Comment: With your solution, if the application self in the pod has issue, kubelet will not restart the pod as well, right?

Comment: @BMW a custom liveness probe for the main container will fix that issue.

Comment: Does this solution work? 
Seems like "Never" is not allowed. Please see this discussion
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/24725